# Нагрузка на MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется скрипт, он принимает пост запрос каждые 5 сек.
В запросе массив из(до) 50 ти строк.
Вот эти 50 строк пишутся в БД. Насколько мощный должен быть сервер, что б выдержал этот секис?

Comment: на смартфоне пятилетней давности можно поднять

Answer (score 1):

Это элементарная нагрузка.
На слабом железе Mysql и 1000 в секунду сможет.

Но в целом рекомендую почитать про предметную оптимизацию, к примеру http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert-speed.html